# Is there a way to cancel Parallel.ForEach loop if it is started as separate task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am building windows service whic main method starting as Task whit cancel token which can be trigger by OnStop event.

Inside main method I want to do two parallel loop for different kind of jobs, etc One loop pooling files from different ftp sites, other one processing it.
I am looking for a way to start Parallel.ForEach loop without  stooping thread .

Something like this

```
private void mainEngine(CancellationToken token)
{
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
    po.CancellationToken = token;
    po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Parallel.ForEach(
                                sklsToProcees, po, currentFolder =>
                            {
                               po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                                string path = currentFolder.ToString();
                                REC.fetchXmls(path, token);
                            });
                        }
                        catch ( TaskCanceledException  ex)
                        {
                            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                        }
                    });
}
```

But looks like this is not working as well ?
My Parallel.ForEach never rise TaskCanceledException
Shoud I pass cacel token also to Task.Factory ?
Do I need somehow to tell Task.Factory that foreach loop is child task.
Or I do not have to vory about stooping Parallel.ForEach if I just stop task whic is executing foreach loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception which is thrown by `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` is caught by your `catch` block which silently swallows the exception. If you want the exception to propogate, i'd suggest removing the catch clause and passing the `CancellationToken` to `Task.Factory.StartNew`

As a side note, you're spinning a parallel loop inside a new `Task` which consumes a ThreadPool thread to do  little work. The overhead may be more than the gain. I'd suggest creating a new thread once and iterating the `while` loop inside.

If `REC.fetchXmls` does IO bound work, then there is no need to be spinning up threads as this kind of work is asynchronous by nature. You can these natur async APIs from the framework.